# Naive Bayes using NaiveBayes and predict - atomic vector?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am running a naive bayes with predict and NaiveBayes, with a few predictor variables, and a binary outcome (lapsed or active). The NB runs fine, but when it comes to the confusion matrix, I get the error:

```
Error in predictions$class : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

do you have any idea how to rectify this? the data was read in as a csv, here is the code:

```
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(thl_new$Lapsed, p=0.65, list=FALSE) 
data_train <- thl_new[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- thl_new[-trainIndex,]
model <- naiveBayes(Lapsed~., data=data_train, laplace = 1)
predictions <- predict(model, data_test[,1:5]) # test accuracy on 'data_test' 
predictions
confusionMatrix(predictions$class, data_test$Lapsed) # show new data estimates
```

Comment: try confusionMatrix(predictions, data_test$Lapsed)

Comment: try confusionMatrix(predictions, data_test$Lapsed)

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly! :-)